# get_template_part - Wordpress not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to place the content of the about page inside a div on the header , the template part is located on folder template-parts/content-about.php

on the header the code is:

```
<div id="slideOut"> 
<div class="slideout-content">

    
    <?php
    while ( have_posts() ) :
        the_post();

        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'about' );

    endwhile; // End of the loop.
    ?>
    
      <?php include 'content-about.php'; ?>
</div><!-- .slideout-content -->
</div>
```

And the content-about.php looks like this:

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
<div class="entry-content">
    <?php
    the_content();

    wp_link_pages(
        array(
            'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . esc_html__( 'Pages:', 'about' ),
            'after'  => '</div>',
        )
    );
    ?>
</div><!-- .entry-content -->
</article><!-- #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->
```

The issue is that is showing on the div the same content as the current page for example if I'm located on home page it shows only the content of the home page inside the div when it should always show the content of the about page.
why is not working?
Thanks

Comment: Because there is nothing in your `content-about.php` telling it to get the content from that page. If you look in your file, you are using `the_content()`. Since that is in the loop, it will get the content from whatever page you are on. You can use `get_the_content()` and pass the about page `id` to that function. Just because the file is named `content-about` doesn't mean that it gets content from that pate.

Comment: thanks can you show me an example, I am new to this part of wordpress.

Comment: Sure. I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`get_template_part()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/) is working as expected. Your `content-about.php` is included normally.

However, it prints the content of the *current* post/page because you're calling [`the_content()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/).

You could replace `the_content()` with `get_the_content()`, passing the post id of your about page as the third parameter.

Note that:

> An important difference from [`the_content()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/) is that `get_the_content()` does not pass the content through the [`the_content`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content/) filter. This means that `get_the_content()` will not auto-embed videos or expand shortcodes, among other things.

So, you might want to use [`apply_filters()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/apply_filters/) like this:

```
<?php
echo apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content( null, false, $about_page_id ) );
// where $about_page_id is the post id of your about page
```

Comment: Thank you , this was a great solution because I had a video placed on the about page that needs to also be displayed inside the header slider

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need the `get_template_part` for this if you don't want.

You can do this:

```
<div id="slideOut"> 
    <div class="slideout-content">
        <?php echo get_the_content('','','your-about-page-id-here'); ?>
    </div><!-- .slideout-content -->
</div>
```

`get_template_part()` is a way to include files with markup that may rely on the loop, but keep things separated. You don't necessarily need it here.

You can also use:
`echo get_post_field('post_content', your-post-id-here );`

Comment: You should pass the about page id as the third parameter of [`get_the_content()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_content/). Also, note that `get_the_content()` does not pass the content through the [`the_content`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content/) filter.

Comment: Correct. However, I'm guessing there are no videos or iFrames in what OP is trying to do, since this looks like a header slider.

Comment: Thank you , it worked well but I do have a video on the about page